# How to apply bootstrap styling to auto-generated form

Tags: go, beego

Using beego render form to build html form
https://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md#renderform

```
type User struct {
Id    int         `form:"-"`
Name  interface{} `form:"username"`
Age   int         `form:"age,text,age:"`
Sex   string
Intro string `form:",textarea"`
}

<form action="" method="post">
{{.Form | renderform}}
</form>
```

This renders the form correctly but with poor html formatting
[image]

What can I do to add bootstrap 4 stlying

Answer (score 0):

Try adding class tags to the struct fields:

```
type User struct {
    Id    int         `form:"-"`
    Name  interface{} `form:"username" class:"form-control"`
    Age   int         `form:"age,text,age:" class:"form-control"`
    Sex   string
    Intro string      `form:",textarea" class:"form-control"`
}

<form action="" method="post">
    {{.Form | renderform}}
</form>
```

The exported func `RenderForm` calls `parseFormTag` for each field of the struct and gets variable `class` in the return ([source code](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/ad0d166d46c8a2dfa3775abf1eae8931a287efeb/templatefunc.go#L449)).

`parseFormTag` gets `class` from the class tag within the struct field tag ([source code](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/ad0d166d46c8a2dfa3775abf1eae8931a287efeb/templatefunc.go#L501)).

`RenderForm` then calls `renderFormField` for that field, passing in `class`. `renderFormField` adds `class` to the string that will eventually be used by `RenderForm` to create the HTML for the form ([source code](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/ad0d166d46c8a2dfa3775abf1eae8931a287efeb/templatefunc.go#L475)).